# How to Bind textbox to Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

i am want to simple these textbox make inside for loop

```
foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="well"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.UserMaster.D1, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
```

But i am face problem in model binding

In above code every textbox is bind  same column name (D1).

But i am want to every textbox is bind different different column like(D1, D2, D3)...etc

please solve this problem

Comment: Why use for loop in this code..

Comment: Do you have 15 textboxes to bind ?

Comment: What do you mean to a different column? Can you provide an example in HTML with what  you want?

Comment: Mr. Mukesh Kalgude ... for loop use for make more textboxes

Comment: Mr Mairaj Ahmad -- Not 15 textboxes to bind this is not fix how many textbox is created it is depend on month

Comment: Mr Jamie Rees --  yes i mean different different column name